# Is left hand side and right side in congruence similar to equality?

Tags: number-theory

I have just began a number theory course and the first homework question is causing difficulty? (Probably a sign I should drop the class)

The question is:

> Let a and n be integers with n>0. Then $a \equiv a \pmod n$.
>
> We will explore several cases where properties of ordinary equality
>   suggest questions about whether congruence works the same the way. For
>   example, in equality, the order of the left-hand side versus the
>   right-hand side of an equals sign does not matter. Is the same true
>   for congruence.

The last time I saw the term "congruence" was in high school geometry. I have been trying to find how that would translate here for the last hour and I can't. Also I am having trouble fitting it into the definitions given in the textbook. Can some please help me get started on a proof for this problem ( or the definitions for mod and congruent).

Comment: Well, what is the definition of this given in the textbook?

Comment: There is not one specifically for these questions. Obviously if there was one I would need to ask here.

Comment: Then what definition from the textbook are you referring to?

Answer (score 0):

$a \equiv a \mod n$

and $a \equiv a \pm kn \mod n$. For any integer $k$.

Usually the official definition is something like $a \equiv b \mod n \iff a -b \equiv 0 \mod n \iff n|(a - b) \iff (a - b) = kn$ for some $k \in \mathbb Z$.

====

It's *similar* to equality and I bet most mathematicians (myself include) think of it as a kind of equality (even though they'll never admit it) but that's not actually correct and one should avoid bad habits from the start.

$a \equiv 3 \mod 4$ means that $a$ belongs inside an "equivalence class" of numbers divisible by 4 with a remainder of 3.  i.e. $a \in \{..., -5, -1, 3, 7,....\}$

It can be squinted at and seen as a type of equality where we are in a cyclic arithmetic with just the numbers {0, 1, 2, 3} repeated over (i.e. we are in $\mathbb Z_4$.  Where 2 + 3 = 5 = 1.  But that... well in a way we are, except what we are adding and expressing are not numbers but *classes* of numbers. 2 is no longer 2 but the entire set {...-6, -2, 2, 6,...}.  So {...-6, - 2, 2, 6,...} "plus" {.....,-5, -1, 3, 7, ...} = {....., -3, 1, 5, ....}.

====

And "congruence" in high school geometry that two objects are the same measure.... So far as I can tell, entirely different concept.

Except in the sense that they are in a way equivalent.  If this triangle over here has sides of length 3, 4, and 5 and that triangle over there has sides of length 3, 4, and 5, then these two different triangles are equivalent for purposes of measure.  They are "congruent".  I can replace one with the other and it doesn't make any practical difference.

If 47 has a remainder of 2 when divided by 5 and 102 has a remainder of 2 when divided by 5 and I work in an assembly line where I pack things into boxes of 5 and at the end of the day I take home whatever doesn't fit in the boxes... then on days when I have to pack 47 and on days when I have to pack 102 I get to take home 2.  Those days are equivalent to me.  In terms of what I got to take home in my pocket, those days are "congruent".  One day is the same as the other for all practical purposes (to me; not my company's customers).

Kind of abstract, huh?